# Why does strcat cause a crash?

Tags: c, strcat

Tell me please why this function may take `'\0'` as second argument, compile and crash?

```
char var[9];
/*some initialization of var */
strcat(var, '\0');
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That function takes a `const char *` as the second parameter. You're passing an `int`.

```
char *strcat(char *restrict s1, const char *restrict s2);
```

You're basically tricking `strcat` into dereferencing `\0` as a pointer - it dereferences `NULL`.

Answer (score 1):

The second argument to `strcat` should be a **pointer** to a null-terminated array of characters.  <s>Your code shouldn't even compile, but if it does, then</s> The result would be **undefined behaviour**.

Comment: It's perfectly okay for it to compile, `'\0'` is the int `0`, a null pointer constant, so the call is `strcat(var, NULL);`. Wrong but valid. Undefined behaviour only if `strcat` doesn't check for null pointers and deal with them appropriately (that means, in practice, it will be UB).

Comment: @DanielFischer: Ah yes, that's a good point; it's valid in this case because it's constant 0.

Answer (score 0):

If the comment is meant to describe the following line (as opposed to act as a place-holder for some actual initialization that's omitted), there's a second scenario:

Since `strcat()` needs to find the end of the first argument in order to figure out where to start concatenating, and you pass it an un-initialized character array, it might well step outside valid memory while looking for the first string's terminating character. Reading outside valid memory can cause crashes on some platforms.

So, it's possible the second argument has nothing to do with why it breaks, although that is, of course, also wrong.

Comment: char var[9];
/*some initialization of var */